# Number of doubles in n independent die rolls

Tags: probability

I am new to probability. Here is my question.

Consider n independent tolls of a fair six-faced die. Say that a double occurs whenever an outcome equals 2 times the one preceding it. For instance, if n = 6 and the outcomes are 1,2,4,3,6,3, then there are 3 doubles.

(i) Let X be the number of doubles observed from n independent tosses. Find the expected value of X.

(ii) Find the variance of X.

I have solved (i) using indicator variables.

Consider $Y_{n} = 1${The n-th outcome equals 2 times the (n-1)-th outcome}

Then $E[Y_{n}]$ is equal to $Pr$(The n-th outcome equals 2 times the (n-1)-th outcome), which is the same as $Pr$(The second outcome equals 2 times the first outcome), for any n $>$ 1.

Then $E[X]$ = $\sum\limits_{i=2}^n E[Y_{i}]$ = $(n-1)E[Y_{2}]$

However, I don't know how to solve (ii). It seems that $Y_{i}$ and $Y_{j}$ are not independent for $i \neq j$. So we can't use $Var[X] = \sum\limits_{i=2}^n Var[Y_{i}]$.

I am stuck here. Could you give me some hints on (ii)?

Comment: Start with the definition of variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Big hint:**

Show $$\operatorname{Var}(X)=E((X-E(X))^2)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2.$$
if you don’t know it already.

Then compute $E(X^2)$ by computing values $E(Y_iY_j),$ for $i,j=2,\dots,n.$

The value $E(X^2)$ depends on three cases: $i=j,$ $|i-j|=1,$  and $|i-j|>1.$

When $i=j,$ $Y_i^2=Y_i.$

When $|i-j|>1,$ show $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent.

The last case is is $E(Y_iY_{i+1}).$ What is required for $Y_i$ and $Y_{i+1}$ to be both $1?$